# Why does sed require 3 backslashes for a regular backslash?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm curious, why does sed need 3 `\` just to recognize one? I'd understand it needing 2, but 3 I don't.

EDIT: here's an example on my Windows computer, using Cygwin:

```
$ echo "sample_input\whatever" | sed "s/\\\/\//"
sample_input/whatever
```

If I don't add 3 backslashes, I get a

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated s' command
```

Comment: It doesn't. Show us why you think it does.

Comment: is your shell consuming an extra level of backslashing?

Comment: one \ for the shell, one \ for the sed, one \ for the backslash = \\\

Comment: @Kimvais: If it was as you stated there, it'd be four, as sed requires an escaped backslash (2) and the shell escaping of those would require one each.

Comment: Use single quotes for `sed` and you can get away with two backslashes.  `echo "sample_input\whatever" | sed 's/\\/\//'` Hopefully someone will come up with the correct explanation for this behavior.

Comment: @Amarghosh nope, that is not the case for win xp cmd.exe and sed from msys-1.0. I get the exact error as in the question and I used single quotes.

Comment: You even need **four backslashes** and two quotes like in `sed "s/.*/\\\\""/"` to print out a single backslash followed by a quote `\"`.

Comment: sorry for my question but you want to replace backslash with a slash?

Comment: It's because you use double quotes therefore the string is interpolated. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash). Using single quotes, this works for me in bash: `sed 's/\///'`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this behavior using Vista and Cygwin 1.7.0.

- Two backslashes produce the error
- *either* three *or* four backslashes work
- Five gives the same error

Two backslashes become a single backslash in the shell which then in sed escapes the forward slash which is the middle delimiter.

```
\\/ -> \/ (which makes the forward slash a regular character instead of a delimiter)
```

Three of them: The first two become one in the shell which then escape the third one in sed

```
\\\/ -> \\/
```

Four: Each pair become single ones in the shell then the first resulting one escapes the second in sed

```
\\\\/ -> \\/
```

**Edit:**

Oh, I forgot to say that both single quotes and double quotes worked the same for me (`cmd.exe` doesn't make the distinction that Bash, et al, makes).

Comment: But `s/\\[0-9]*//` seems correct if the char after the backslash is not slash

Answer (score 14):

Your shell (probably bash) is doing its own escaping, and that's confusing you.  You can use an echo command to see what is being passed, or it's easy to write a custom program (commonly named "showargs" or similar):

```
$ echo "s/\\\/\//"
s/\\/\//
$ echo "s/\\/\//"
s/\/\//
```

You can also use single quotes, which are treated differently in bash.

Comment: I'm using Windows's `cmd.exe`, not bash.

Comment: @Geo: I guessed bash because you mentioned cygwin, but other shells also do escaping too.

Answer (score 7):

That's due to `sh`'s double-quoted string parsing rule.

[Posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_07) specifies how `sh` parses double-quoted strings.

> The backslash shall retain its special meaning as an escape character (see Escape Character (Backslash)) only when followed by one of the following characters when considered special:
> $   `   "   \

In other words, `sh` lefts the backslash which is followed by characters other than `$` `'` `"` `\`.

So, if `sh` meets the double-quoted string `sed "s/\\\/\//"`, `sh` parses it as follows.

1. The first two `\\` is changed into `\`. Because the first `\`  is followed by the second `\`.
2. The third and fourth `\` is still left in the string. Because both of them are followed by `/`, which is not special in double-quoted string.

After pasring, `sh` passes the string `s/\\/\//` to `sed`,  which substitutes the first occurence of `\` into `/`.

With same reasoning, when `sh` meets the string, `"sed s/\\\\/\//"`, `sh` passes `/\\/\//` to `sed`, which also substitutes the first occurence of `\` into `/`.

Answer (score 4):

Please show an example of what you have in future. in sed, say you want to replace a "`\`"  with pipe (|), for example

```
$ cat file
asklfja \ asf

$ sed 's/\\/|/g' file
asklfja | asf

$ sed 's%\\%|%g' file #using different delimiter
asklfja | asf
```

you just need to escape it once.

Edit: To @OP's example, since you are using cmd.exe and not bash/ksh, cmd.exe doesn't like single quotes. I cannot produce your scenario. This works for my GNU sed on windows using 2 slashes

eg

```
C:\test>echo "sample_input\whatever" | sed "s/\\/\//"
"sample_input/whatever"
```

Comment: @ghostdog74, I posted an example.

Comment: I'm not using bash, ghostdog74, and with single quotes, I get the same error.

Comment: so in cygwin what shell are you using? you must be using a shell to run your commands.

Comment: Right now, I'm just using cygwin binaries, from a Windows command prompt.

Comment: ok, i could not produce your error. works fine for me with GNU sed and cmd.exe. hope somebody with cygwin can help you.

Answer (score 2):

In my version of CYGWIN, it works as the original poster says, but, works differently (normally) if I use single quotes.

```
$ echo "sample_input\whatever" | sed 's/\\/\//'
sample_input/whatever
```

```
$ echo "sample_input\whatever" | sed "s/\\/\//"
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

Hmmm..

Comment: Just this should be enough: `sed 's/\///'`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you assuming `\\\n` or `\\\t` as three backslashes there, but actually, its 2 backslashes and another patterns

```
   backslash          \\
   newline            \n
   tab                \t
```

also, `/` might need to escape because in `s/.../`, `/` is using for open and close parts.

so `/\\\/\//` would be `\\ + \/ + \/` according to your updated example

Comment: I like your method in explaining, could you please take a look at this and try to answer it? https://superuser.com/questions/1249497/sed-needs-n-to-append-new-line?noredirect=1#comment1834908_1249497

Answer (score 0):

Replacing one backslash with two on my Cygwin requires this expression:

sed -e "s|\\|\\\\|g"