# sed command not replacing "\"

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am using sed to replace a content in a file with string "dba01upc\Fusion_test".  After the replacement I  see the '\' character is  missing. The replaced string is dba01upcFusion_test .  Looks like sed is ignoring '\' while replacing..
Can anyone let me  know the sed command to include all characters?

My Sed Command:

```
sed -i "s%{"sara_ftp_username"}%"dba01upc\Fusion_test"%g" /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml
```

Before Replacement :  Sara.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ser:service-account >
<ser:description/>
<ser:static-account>
<con:username>{sara_ftp_username}</con:username>
</ser:static-account>
</ser:service-account>
```

After  Replacement :  Sara.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ser:service-account>
<ser:description/>
<ser:static-account>
<con:username>dba01upcFusion_test</con:username>
</ser:static-account>
</ser:service-account>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i 's%{sara_ftp_username}%dba01upc[\]Fusion_test%g' /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml
# or
sed -i 's%{sara_ftp_username}%dba01upc\\Fusion_test%g' /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml
# or
sed -i "s%{sara_ftp_username}%dba01upc\\\Fusion_test%g" /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml
```

escape the `\` (twice if double quote)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i "s%sara_ftp_username%dba01upc\\\Fusion_test%g" /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml
```

Comment: Why three backslashes rather than two or four?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.. I have another situation.. I am using the environment variable in sed command and I am getting the same problem(the "\" is not getting replaced)..

export value="dba01upc\Fusion_test"

sed -i "s%{"sara_ftp_username"}%$value%g" /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml
can u pls let me know if you have any suggestion to fix this ?

Comment: Use this: `export value="dba01upc\\\Fusion_test"
sed -i "s%sara_ftp_username%$value%g" /home_ldap/user1/placeholder/Sara.xml`

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: Please refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash