# Replace a double backslash followed by quote (\\') using sed?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed

I am unable to replace double backslash followed by quote `\\'` in sed. This is my current command

```
echo file.txt | sed "s:\\\\':\\':g"
```

The above command not only replaces `\\'` with `\'` it also replaces `\'` with `'`

How could I just replace exact match?

Input:

```
'one', 'two \\'change', 'three \'unchanged'
```

Expected:

```
'one', 'two \'change', 'three \'unchanged'
```

Actual:

```
'one', 'two \'change', 'three 'unchanged'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ sed "s/\\\\\\\'/\\\'/g" file
'one', 'two \'change', 'three \'unchanged'
```

[Here is a discussion on why sed needs 3 backslashes for one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2369314/3150943)

Comment: Can you explain why you only need to escape the backslash once?

Comment: it didn't work on my example. This also replaces `\'` with `'`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
sed "s/\\\\\'/\\\'/g"
```