# Escape backslash character in sed

Tags: sed

I need to modify some Windows paths.

For instance,

```
D:\usr
```

to

```
D:\first\usr
```

So, I have created a variable.

```
$path = "first\usr"
```

then used the following command:

```
sed -i -e 's!\\usr!${path}/g;' test.txt
```

However, this ends up with the following:

```
D:\firstSr
```

How do I escape `\u` in sed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sed require 3 backslashes for a regular backslash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash)

Comment: you need to double escape the content of new value also, not only the sed search pattern

Comment: What shell or scripting language are you using? `$path = "first\usr"` looks like Perl, but the rest doesn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `path` variable was assigned properly (without spaces in the assignment: `path='first\usr'`), fixing step by step for an input file `test.txt` with one example path:

```
$ cat test.txt
D:\usr
```

1. Your original command

   ```
   $ sed 's!\\usr!${path}/g;' test.txt
   sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
   ```

   doesn't do much, as you've mixed `!` and `/` as the delimiter.
2. Fixing delimiters:

   ```
   $ sed 's!\\usr!${path}!g;' test.txt
   D:${path}
   ```

   Now no interpolation happens at all because of the single quotes. I suspect these are just copy-paste mistakes, as you obviously got some output.
3. Double quotes:

   ```
   $ sed "s!\\usr!${path}!g" test.txt
   bash: !\\usr!${path}!g: event not found
   ```

   Now this clashes with [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html). We could escape the `!`, or use a different delimiter.
4. `/` as delimiter:

   ```
   $ sed "s/\\usr/${path}/g" test.txt
   D:\firstSr
   ```

   *Now* we're where the question actually started. `${path}` expands to `first\usr`, but `\u` has a special meaning in GNU sed in the replacement string: it uppercases the following character, hence the `S`.

   Even without the special meaning, `\u` would most likely just expand to `u` and the backslash would be gone.
5. Escaping the backslash:

   ```
   $ path='first\\usr'
   $ sed "s/\\usr/${path}/g" test.txt
   D:\first\usr
   ```

   This works.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which shell you are using, you may be able to use parameter expansion to double `\` in your substitution string and prevent the `\u` interpretation:

```
path="first\usr"
sed -e "s/\\usr/${path//\\/\\\\}/g" <<< "D:\usr"
```

The syntax for replacing a pattern with the shell parameter expansion is `${parameter/pattern/string}` (one replacement) or `${parameter//pattern/string}` (replace all matches).

This substitution is not specified by POSIX, but is available in Bash.

Where it is not available, you may need to filter `$path` through a process:

```
path=$(echo "$path" | sed 's/[][\\*.%$]/\\&/g')
```

(N.B. I have also quoted other sed metacharacters in this filter).