# Make oneliner of sed-command

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

After a lot of trying the past day, I can't make following command work on 1 line:

```
sed '/'"$var1"'/ {n;n;a '\'"$var2"\'' \\ 
}' tempproject.cfg
```

when i run this like above, it matches $var1 and replaces the 3rd line after it with $var2.

example of what the sed command should do:

```
  var1=c
  var2=hello
a                                                              a
b                                                              b         
c                                                              c
d      =>     sed '/'"$var1"'/ {n;n;a '\'"$var2"\'' \\  =>     d
e              }' tempproject.cfg                              e
f                                                              'hello' \
g                                                              g
h                                                              h
```

when i put the command on 1 line i get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first $var1=c => var1=c then  $var2=hello var2=hello

Comment: fixed. any clue to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var1=c
$var2=hello
$sed "/$var1/{n;n;n;s/.*/'$var2' \\\  /}" tempproject.cfg
```

should give you

```
a
b
c
d
e
'hello' \  
g
h
i
```

Why use [three backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash)?