# Replace JSON key using SED

Tags: json, string, bash, sed, replace

I am trying to get a JSON key and change its property in the file using `-i` flag with sed. The issue is, I cannot get this regex right. It works perfectly fine for the simple replace case, but I cannot get it working using this regex. For simplicity, I have just tried a simple echo, rather than saving it to the file. Ideas?

```
 x=0.0.179     
 echo "version: 0.0.178" | sed 's/^[ ]*\"version\"[ ]*:[ ]*\"\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)\".*$/\$x/'
 0.0.178
```

Comment: What's your JSON, what do you expect, and what do you actually get ?

Comment: If you're trying to edit JSON, there are tools for that (e.g. `jq`). An approach using sed is probably going to break at some point.

Comment: @brian I think the expectation is well explained in my question. I am expecting to get that 0.0.178 replaced by 0.0.179. I am only restricted to sed, so I cannot use jq. Is there a way I can do it with sed?

Comment: Is there a reason for not installing jq? Doesn't your server has Python installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should you be complicating it with `sed`, just do,

```
x="0.0.179"
echo "version: 0.0.178" | sed  "s/version: .*/version: $x/"
version: 0.0.179
```

and *`BTW`* if your `JSON` input can be parsed and modified via `jq`, go for it. Use this *ONLY* as a last resort.

Comment: This is a pretty solid answer.  Using sed with double quoted expressions is difficult if you include ANY backslashes in the expression.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369314/why-does-sed-require-3-backslashes-for-a-regular-backslash for details.

Comment: I completely agree: Using `"` in  sed is bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

I think your sed regexp is looking for the version number *within* double-quotes. Your input to sed above is not quoted as such, and hence doesn't get replaced (I'd expect your JSON to be double-quoted though, hence my interest above re. your real JSON input).

Answer (score 1):

This works. Mention the `'`s around `$x`

```
echo "version: 0.0.178" | sed 's/^[ ]*\"version\"[ ]*:[ ]*\"\([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\)\".*$/\'$x'/'
```

Bash variables do not get replaced inside strings with `'`. Use `"` whenever possible to avoid this, or just concat your variable into the command as shown above.

Comment: Yes, one could also short this. But I tried to answer the specific question.